# Uninstalling Lando application in usr/local/bin

Tags: macos, applications

What is the best way of uninstalling an application in usr/local/bin/.  This application was installed thru terminal.

Answer (score 1):

According to their [docs here](https://docs.lando.dev/basics/uninstalling.html#macos), to uninstall the app:

- Mount the DMG you downloaded to install Lando. [Visit GitHub](https://github.com/lando/lando/releases) if you no longer have the DMG
- Double click on the uninstall.command script
- Agree to remove Lando and enter your user password when prompted

Comment: This is the response after following the instruction above.                                       

 Are you sure you want to remove Lando? (Y/N): y
Making sure Lando is powered down...
/Volumes/Lando 3.6.0/uninstall.command: line 22: /usr/local/bin/lando: Bad CPU type in executable.

Is it ok to uninstall a program directly from usr/local/bin?  If yes, what will be the syntax.

Comment: @jespir Without knowing more about how you initially installed lando, I can't really comment. It could be that you downloaded the incorrect version from the site. Make sure you download the correct architecture version.

If you have a Mac with an Intel processor, download https://github.com/lando/lando/releases/download/v3.6.1/lando-x64-v3.6.1.dmg

If you have a Mac with an M1/Arm chip, download this version https://github.com/lando/lando/releases/download/v3.6.1/lando-arm64-v3.6.1.dmg

Comment: I downloaded Lando ver 360x64 from older intel chip https://github.com/lando/lando/releases/download/v3.6.0/lando-x64-v3.6.0.dmg.  I understand Docker is already included in the package.